# Python read csv to dict quotes missing

Tags: python, csv

I have a tab delimited csv file like below:

```
"land"."monkey" "land"."dog"
"see"."fish"    "see"."shell"
```

which I read and build a dict with:

```
import argparse
currentSources = open('currentSources.csv', 'r')
find_replace_dict = {}

with currentSources as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    find_replace_dict = dict((rows[0],rows[1]) for rows in reader)

print find_replace_dict
```

I´d expect the output of find_replace_dict like

```
{'"land"."monkey"': '"land"."dog"', '"see"."fish"': '"see"."shell"'}
```

but instead, get it as:

```
{'land."monkey"': 'land."dog"', 'see."fish"': 'see."shell"'}
```

Here double-quotes of land and see are missing. 
I already tried to tell the reader to quote everything with

```
reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

which does not bring any difference.

How can I keep all the double-quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening your file, explicitly instruct Python that the quotechar is not applicable, and set it to `None`

The below should help you get the desired output:

```
with currentSources as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quotechar=None)
```

Comment: great! This is doing it!

Answer (score 0):

```
reader = csv.reader(currentSources, delimiter='\t', quotechar=None)
```

Tidying it up by removing the `with` statement.